# Construct Class Names Dynamically in Sass

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to construct class names dynamically inside a mixin?

Here is my calling class:

```
.call-view { @include record-view('call-view'); }
```

Here is my attempt to dynamically create classes:

```
@mixin record-view($namespace) {
  .$namespace__title {
    @extend %title;
    padding: ($gridsize / 2) $gridsize;
    background: $lightgray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid darken($lightgray, 5%);
  }

  .$namespace__content { padding: $gridsize; }

  footer { @extend %footer; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delimit the variable to use it in a class name.

`.#{$namespace}__title`

Comment: Specifically, [string interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_).